# Previously working .htaccess in codeigniter 3.1.2 not working after trying prerender.io

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, prerender

I was using the following configuration in .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It was working fine and the home page was displayed as soon as I entered www.my-site.com.

Then I tried to implement prerender.io in codeigniter using the .htaccess file provided in this link: https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354. The new .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "MY_TOKEN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://www.my-site.com/$2 [P,L]
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I also tried the comment of @benceg just below the post but this also did not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(index\.php)?(.*) http://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$3 [P,L]
```

The above .htaccess file did not work, and worse yet, when I replaced my previous (the one mentioned at the beginning) fully working .htaccess file back, it was also not working.

When I entered www.my-site.com, it showed me “Website under construction”.

Then I tried www.my-site.com/mycontroller and, to my surprise, my home page was being shown. This clearly indicates that my .htaccess file (which was previously fully working) is now “partially” working.

But again when I tried www.my-site.com, it showed “Website under construction”.

Some codeigniter configurations that I currently have:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.my-site.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$route['default_controller'] = 'mycontroller';
```

I am using Bluehost Shared Hosting service and I know they support mod-rewrite.

I do not want prerender.io anymore. What did I enable or disable while trying the new (prerender.io version) .htaccess? What can I do to get my fully working "previous state" back?

I tried to search the net for similar issues but did not find anything specific to my problem.

**Update:**

I tried using the first (previously working) .htaccess file on local lampp server and it is working as usual but it is still not working on Bluehost server.

**Update 2:**

An interesting finding I made today. When I am checking my site's (address: northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net) speed on Google, the page is being rendered correctly. But when I am accessing the above mentioned link in a browser I am instantly redirected to http://northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi .

Comment: @John I tried to reset. But the result was the same. Even after deleting the index.html file within the public_html folder, the "page under construction" is still being shown.

Comment: @RajaMukherjee have you tried Sorav Garg comment solution ?

Comment: @John Yes I tried. But it did not work. I requested Bluehost to factory reset the File Manager part of my account. They have not replied yet.

Comment: Ok ok. Let me know after that. What is the URL of your website just to have a look ?

Comment: @John The (temporary) url is http://northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net . But it is giving me a big "sorry" even after deleting the default index.html file. So I am having to use http://northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net/nsm .

Comment: @John What I want is to basically redirect the user to northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net/nsm when northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net is entered. It was happening at the beginning using the settings I mentioned in the question but I don't know what went wrong that it is not working anymore.

Comment: Hum... actually when I reach your URL I have the homepage correctly shown. By the way, it's the same page than /nsm. Maybe you have corrected the problem ?

Comment: @John What do you mean? http://northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net/ is not opening at my place. It is showing the "sorry" page. /nsm is the name of the CI controller. When I am adding the controller, i.e. northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net/nsm (Mark the /nsm), to the url then everything is ok. Did you check the first url?

Comment: @John Please see my second update. It may be of some help.

Comment: I tried and for me, I can access your site successfully by using http://northernschoolofmusic.com.cp-in-13.webhostbox.net/ ! I think you have problem with your browser or internet provider... Can you try with another computer and internet connexion ? Furthermore, it would be ok with your second update.

Comment: @John You were right my friend. The problem was with my internet connection. Struggled more than 5 days with the same issue. Finally, solved. Thank you Thank you Thank you my friend. You saved me. Leave the internet connection problem as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: done ! Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally the internet connexion. The Internet Provider may have saved the DNS incorrectly and redirected to a wrong cached page.
Changing the browser or the connexion provider was the solution !

Comment: Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

use this htaccess -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and config settings should be like that

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.my-site.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

please follow this it will work...

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I am sorry to say it did not work in my case. I requested Bluehost to factory reset the File Manager part of my account. They have not replied yet.